# local configuration files are not loading and ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust failing in offline mode of Angular 15 PWA application

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa, ngsw-config

I Added PWA package to my angular application. Angular CLI version is 15.2.9 and serviceworker version is also 15.2.9. I am facing an issue with the service worker. The service worker is registered on its own through the app.module. It works fine in online mode. But when I change the network to offline mode,local configured json flies are not loading and ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust failing.

[serverconfig file is not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9C0O.png).

expecting to work the pwa application in offline mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust failing in offline mode of Angular 8 PWA application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048665/ngsw-jsonngsw-cache-bust-failing-in-offline-mode-of-angular-8-pwa-application)

Comment: no, it did not solved.